# Argument won't pass

Tags: python, class, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am making a basic GUI app using tkinter that gathers user input to populate a docx template.
There is too much code so I'll just post where I think the problem is. Here's my button.

```
self.my_button = Button(self.master, text="Create the Contract",
                            command=lambda: self.create_contract(self.name_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.address_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.city_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.postal_code_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.phone_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.email_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.arrival_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.departure_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.total_nights_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.before_tax_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.total_nights_entry.get(),
                                                                 calculations.gst(self.before_tax_entry.get()),
                                                                 calculations.tvq(self.before_tax_entry.get()),
                                                                 calculations.minitax(self.before_tax_entry.get())
                                                                 ))

    self.my_button.grid(row=10, column=0)

    self.master.mainloop()

def create_contract(self, name, address, city, postal_code, phone, email, arrival, departure, before_tax, total_nights, gst_tax, tvq_tax, mini_tax):
    contract_template.CreateContract(name, address, city, postal_code, phone, email, arrival, departure, before_tax, total_nights, gst_tax, tvq_tax, mini_tax)
```

calculations:

```
def gst(before_tax):
    guest_gst = int(before_tax) * 0.05
    return guest_gst

def tvq(before_tax):
    guest_tvq = int(before_tax) * 0.09975
    return guest_tvq

def minitax(total_nights):
    guest_minitax = int(total_nights) * 2
    return guest_minitax
```

Right now, when I run the app, the GUI gets displayed, I have all my entries and button, but when I click the button:

```
>>> import GUIcontract
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "GUIcontract.py", line 76, in <lambda>
    calculations.minitax(self.before_tax_entry.get())
TypeError: create_contract() takes exactly 14 arguments (15 given)
>>>
```

I have been going at this for the last 8 hours. I wish my laptop were sturdier so I could throw it.
 Clearly the problem is with

```
calculations.minitax(self.before_tax_entry.get())
```

Comment: Take another look at the arguments you're passing. There's an odd one out.

Comment: You're passing `self.total_nights_entry.get()` twice ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple solution is to not use lambda in this way. You're making things way too hard. Since all of those variables are attributes on the object, you can get them in the callback. There's no reason to pass them into the function.

```
self.my_button = Button(..., command=self.create_contract)
...
def create_contract(self):
    name = self.name_entry.get()
    address = self.address_entry.get()
    ...
```

The end result is the same, but the code is much easier to understand and manage. Long lists of arguments are prone to this sort of very common error (passing in the wrong number of arguments), so it's best to avoid long argument lists whenever possible.

A good rule of thumb is to never use a lambda if you have to pass more than a couple arguments.

Comment: The problem isn't `lambda` (despite Guido's deep hatred of it), it's the fact that *any* function has more than 2 or 3 arguments, in my opinion. Anonymous functions are no different from regular functions -- if you ever write a function with that many arguments (except in some special case like handling input that's coming to you from some place you don't have control over), something has gone wrong.

Comment: This is excellent advice. Anytime your function has more than 4 or 5 arguments, it's worth considering whether it can be revised. (Edit: opinions clearly differ on where to draw the line, but the general principle is that too many arguments == a function in need of refactoring.)

Comment: Agreed it's very confusing. What are the alternatives for reducing large amounts of arguments in a function? Diluting with more functions? @Bryan Oakley

Comment: @z82n: another simple solution is to use keyword args, so you're at least forced to match the value with a parameter name. You still end up with hard-to-read code, at least it's _explicit_ hard-to-read code.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing an extra argument inside

```
command=lambda: self.create_contract(self.name_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.address_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.city_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.postal_code_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.phone_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.email_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.arrival_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.departure_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.total_nights_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.before_tax_entry.get(),
                                                                 self.total_nights_entry.get(),
                                                                 calculations.gst(self.before_tax_entry.get()),
                                                                 calculations.tvq(self.before_tax_entry.get()),
                                                                 calculations.minitax(self.before_tax_entry.get())
                                                                 ))
```

You've declared the function to have 14 arguments (including `self`), but you're passing 15 (again, including `self`). I don't know which one is the extra one, because it is very difficult to read functions with 15 arguments. You should strongly, strongly, strongly consider refactoring this so that it no longer has 15 arguments. Look in to the Builder Pattern, or maybe the Argument Pattern.

EDIT: Evidently the extra argument is

```
self.total_nights_entry.get(),
self.before_tax_entry.get(),    
self.total_nights_entry.get(),
```

as was pointed out by mgilson in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_contract(self, name, address, city, postal_code, phone, email, arrival, departure, before_tax, total_nights, gst_tax, tvq_tax, mini_tax):
```

1. self, 2. name, 3. address, 4. city, 5. postal_code, 6. phone, 7. email, 8. arrival, 9. departure, 10. before_tax, 11. total_nights, 12. gst_tax, 13. tvq_tax, 14. mini_tax

`create_contract` takes 14 args including self.

```
self.create_contract(
     1. self.name_entry.get(),
     2. self.address_entry.get(),
     3. self.city_entry.get(),
     4. self.postal_code_entry.get(),
     5. self.phone_entry.get(),
     6. self.email_entry.get(),
     7. self.arrival_entry.get(),
     8. self.departure_entry.get(),
     9. self.total_nights_entry.get(),
    10. self.before_tax_entry.get(),
    11. self.total_nights_entry.get(),
    12. calculations.gst(self.before_tax_entry.get()),
    13. calculations.tvq(self.before_tax_entry.get()),
    14. calculations.minitax(self.before_tax_entry.get())
)
```

`create_contract` being passed 14 args NOT INCLUDING self.

Answer (score 0):

in Button

```
self.total_nights_entry.get()
```

is called twice